# submit form with wrap wrapped tag

Tags: jquery, function, hyperlink, submit

I have a code where when a user selects a check box the `label` will turn into a link to submit the form. I can get the `label` to change to a link but when I use the link as a submit button it only returns the url with `#` Here's what I've tried.

```
$('#checkbox').change(function() {
    var c = this.checked ? '#f00' : '#09f';
    $('label').css('color', c);
    var $this = $(this);
    $('label').wrap('<a href="#" id="sublink"></a>');
    $('a').link('href', '#');
});

$('#sublink').bind('click', function() {
    $('#formname').submit();
});​
```

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Delegate the event**

```
$('body').on('click','#sublink', function() // For jQuery > 1.7
```

---

```
$('body').delegate('#sublink','click',function() // For jQuery < 1.7
```

body can be replaced with any static parent container which encases the anchor Tag.
The closer the better

**UPDATE**

```
$('body').on('click','#sublink', function(e){ 
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#formname').submit();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using 1.8 and I've tried what you've suggested but its still loading the page with #. here is my code: `$('#checkbox').change(function(){
    var c = this.checked ? '#f00' : '#09f';
    $('label').css('color', c);
   var $this = $(this); 
    $('label').wrap('<a href="#" id="sublink"></a>'); $('a').link('href', '#');


$('a').on('click','#sublink', function(){
      $('#formname'').submit();
});
});`

Comment: Change this line $('a').on('click','#sublink', function(){ to $('body').on('click','#sublink', function(e){  and add e.preventDefault();

Comment: For some reason it isn't working in my particular case. From how my file is set up there are multiple check boxes with labels that are generated with `PHP`. Basically multiple links to submit the same form. I just have to figure out what is going on there. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Sorry one thing more, when I add your code it for some reason is canceling the `change` function. Nothing is happening when I click my check box.

Comment: Is the checkbox too being dynamically added

Comment: opps never mind, lol It works great thank you. I just needed to move somethings around.